Разбиение текста в две коллекции по типу данных?
Есть задача - разбить текст по двум коллекциям: в первую нужно перенести только численные значения, во вторую - перенести каждый атрибут без пробела.
string strophe_template = "11А 9Б 11А 9Б 11А 9Б 11А 9Б 11А 9Б 11А 9Б"

По итогу содержание коллекций должно быть следующим:
Первая коллекция
[11 9 11 9 11 9 11 9 11 9 11 9]
Вторая коллекция
[11А 9Б 11А 9Б 11А 9Б 11А 9Б 11А 9Б 11А 9Б]
Соответственно возникает вопрос как это сделать?

Формат значения всегда одинаковый? То есть сначала число, а в конце одна буква? Если да, то просто отсеките последний символ и сконвертируйте полученное в int если надо, будет у вас 2 коллекции в итоге. Если формат разный, то хотелось бы видеть все возможные комбинации.

Общая фабула "численная часть+буквенная часть" сохраняется, однако длина "буквенной части" может варьироваться: условно "9АРБУЗ 12БУЛОЧКА 9АНАФЕМА". Технически, если ограничить возможности до 1-2 знаков в числовой части, а в буквенной оставить только одну, то да, способ рабочий.

Вот эту важную информацию надо добавлять в вопрос, ибо как видите, решить задачу можно по разному. Если у вас цифры и слова разные, то тут 2 варианта: 1. Цикл - условный 12БУЛОЧКА посимвольно до тех пор, пока char.IsDigit() (является цифрой) выдает true, попутно добавляя символ в отдельную коллекцию, тем самым вы отделите цифры от букв. 2. Регулярные выражения - используете Regex условие, которое разделит вашу строку на нужные вам части, ну допустим @"(\d+)(\D+)" должен вернуть из 11A массив [ "11", "A" ], дальше уже делайте что надо с полученными данными.

Очень легко с помощью регулярок делается.
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string strophe_template = "11А 9Б 11А 9Б 11А 9Б 11А 9Б 11А 9Б 11А 9Б";
    var matches = Regex.Matches(strophe_template, @"(\d+)\w+");

    string[] first = matches.Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value).ToArray();
    string[] second = matches.Select(m => m.Groups[0].Value).ToArray();

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", first));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", second));
}

Вывод в консоль
11 9 11 9 11 9 11 9 11 9 11 9
11А 9Б 11А 9Б 11А 9Б 11А 9Б 11А 9Б 11А 9Б


Бесплатная книга по .NET и C#: Книга по C#
Киниги по Экосистеме C#: https://metanit.com/sharp/
Сайт обучения Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/
    string strophe_template = "11А 9Б 11А 9Б 11А 9Б 11А 9Б 11А 9Б 11А 9Б";

    // Вторая коллекция:
    var second_collection = strophe_template.Split(' ');

    // Первая коллекция:
    var first_collection = second_collection.Select(code => code.Replace(code.Last().ToString(), ""));

    // Если нужно конвертировать в целые:
    // TODO: Удалить если не нужно:
    var second_collectionByte = second_collection.Select(code => byte.Parse(code));


Советую вникать в задачу, перед тем как отвечать, а если что-то не понятно, спросите автора. P.S. делаете много лишних телодвижений.

string strophe_template = "11А 9Б 11А 9Б 11А 9Б 11А 9Б 11А 9Б 11А 9Б";
    
string[] parts = strophe_template.Split(' ');

var numbersCollection = parts.Where(p => int.TryParse(p, out _)).Select(int.Parse).ToList();
var attributesCollection = parts.Where(p => !int.TryParse(p, out _)).ToList();


Split по умолчанию и так разбивает по пробелу, указывает его там бессмысленно. И да, прочитайте задачу еще раз...
